# How to add your organization's location in Google search?

Tags: google, google-search

For example, if I google one organization, the search result shows this:

[image: SurveyMETER Google Search result]

I want to do the same for my organization. We already have website, social media, etc. But how to add this info in Google Search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add and manage business places here:
[Google My Business](https://www.google.com/business/)